# Dragonborn Item Interaction

Tags: dnd-4e

I have a question in regards to resistances...

If I had the Wyrmtouched Amulet from the Adventurers Vault and my character was a dragonborn using the Scion of Arkhosia Paragon Path what would my resistances be due to the amulet?  I'm wondering if it would be cold, fire, thunder, acid, and lightning all at once.

The amulet has a property that says "If you are a dragonborn, gain resist 10 to the same type of damage dealt by your dragon breath power. After you use your dragon breath power, the resistance increases to 20 until the end of your next turn."

The Paragon Path has at lvl 11 Versatile Breath that says "Whenever you attack with your dragon breath racial power, choose one of the following damage types: acid, cold, fire, lightning, or poison. The attack’s damage is also that type."

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My personal interpretation would be that the amulet would grant the resistance based on the type of breath weapon you originally had at 1st level, regardless of what the paragon path may alter about your breath weapon.

The *Scion of Arkhosia* seems to set a precedent for doing that. It uses your breath weapon damage type in three other cases, and all three state that they use *"the same type you initially chose for your dragon breath racial power"*.

This is something you should discuss with your GM, but as GM I would probably base it on your 1st level breath type; having it any other way makes the amulet extremely powerful for being an uncommon item.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a conflict between two rules that never expected or accounted for each others' existence. The Wyrmtouched Amulet appears to only be expecting you to have the regular dragon breath power - which only has one damage type, ever.

I doubt you would have resistance to *all* types - that would be incredibly powerful.

This is something to discuss with your GM. You have some options: Perhaps it should go by the element you originally chose for your dragon breath before you acquired Versatile Breath. Perhaps its resistance type should match whichever single element your dragon breath last used, and any resistance it grants you switches type when you use a different element of dragon breath. There are probably other possibilities, and it's up to you and your GM to work out how it should work.